# Upgrade kernel for linux system without upgrading user apps/libs?

Tags: linux, kernel, upgrade, glibc, uefi

I built a custom Linux "recovery-cd" image that consists of a compressed `initrd` and boots via `bcdedit` (like Ubuntu Wubi) instead of a physical CD. It has various recovery tools for partition editing, antivirus, etc.

Now I have to upgrade the kernel and modules to make it support `UEFI`, so it can boot in a SecureBoot-enabled machine (I'm using a signed grubx64.efi for booting).

My image is based on TinyCore Linux 3.x, which added UEFI support (linux 3.10) in the latest 5.x versions. I replaced the 2.6.32 kernel and modules with 3.10 and things appear to work. But TinyCore  3.x has glibc 2.11, while 5.x has glibc 2.17.

My question is, how do I make sure there are no incompatibilities between the new kernel and older user apps/libs. I am looking out for removed syscalls and features in all kernel release notes between 2.6.32 and 3.10, but what would a more thorough approach be ? Am I just asking for trouble by doing this ?

Comment: It is a bad idea. Something is bound to break and the failure will be subtle or odd. Probably fine within the major kernel version but from 2.6.x to 3.x I would not trust it.

Answer (score 2):

Such a major version change is bound to cause failures in apps and libs. There are quite a lot of changes between the two versions you mentioned. Usually it is ok to jump within sub-versions, e.g. 2.6.32 to 2.6.39. Jumping all the way from 2.6.x to 3.x is not recommended.